# composition of transformations P_1 --> P_2

Tags: linear-algebra

let $T_1 : P_1 \to P_2$ be a linear transformation defined by $T_1(p(x))=xp(x)$

and $T_2:P_2 \to P_2$ be a linear operator defined by $T_2(p(x))=p(2x+1)$

$B=\{1,x\}, B'=\{1,x,x^2\}$

a) Find $[T_2 \circ T_1]_{B',B}$,$[T_2]_{B'}$,$[T_1]_{B',B}$

b) state a formula relating matrices in part (a)

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300429/linear-transformation-of-polynomials)

Comment: IN $P_1$ it'll have form $ax+b$ so I figured $T_2 \circ T_1(a,b)$ and $P_2$ has form $ax^2+bx+c$ which in component form is $(a,b,c)$ but I'm stuck after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T_1(1) = x$ and $T_1(x) = x^2$.

So $[T_1(1)]_{B',B} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $[T_1(x)]_{B',B} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Therefore $[T_1]_{B',B} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Hint for $T_2$:
$T_2(1) = 1=1(1)+0(x)+0(x^2)$, $T_2(x)=2x+1 = 1(1)+2(x)+0(x^2)$, and $T_2(x^2)=(2x+1)^2 = 4x^2+4x+1=1(1)+4(x)+4(x^2)$.

Comment: so then $T_2(a,b,c)= (a(2x+1)^2, b(2x+1),c)$

so $[T_2]_{B'} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&1&1\\4&2&0\\4&0&0\end{array}\right]$

Comment: I would generally order the columns the other way (look up the ordering your professor uses), but yes.

Comment: the answer key has $[T_2 \circ T_1]_{B',B} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}4&0\\4&2\\1&1\end{array}\right]$

column ordering you mean reverse the order. so x^2,x,1 from top to bottom as opposed to bottom to top

got it, thanks!

Comment: Then your professor orders them like $[T_1] = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $[T_2] = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.  Yes, that's what I meant.